# SQL Server : UPDATE MyTable SET col1 = value, col2 = col1

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table col1 float, col2 float with the following data:

> 1,2
>
> 3,4

After the query:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET col1 = 100, col2 = col1
```

is executed, the rows are:

> 100,1
>
> 100,3

Obviously, the old, not updated value of col1 is used, when col2 is being updated. Is it possible to update the col2 with the new value, referring col1 or I have to write the value (100) twice? I want to use auto-generated queries and it's easier to keep formulas.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another alternative to try:

```
DECLARE @x float;

UPDATE MyTable
SET
  @x = col1 = formula,
  col2 = @x * …
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

or:

```
DECLARE @x float;

UPDATE MyTable
SET
  @x = formula,
  col1 = @x,
  col2 = @x * …
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

`OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` is there to ensure the sequential order of evaluation of assignments.

Comment: Well, the first example is called a "quirky update" - I'd be very cautious of this syntax. See these questions for potential gotchas, disclaimers that it isn't guaranteed to work in the future, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082481/sql-2005-8-quirky-update-black-arts-question & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653962/ms-sql-query-update-record-retrieved-via-stored-procedure

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll just use variables with the same names as columns have and will change formula format to use @ (it's OK for the solution).

Answer (score 2):

Your `UPDATE` statement sees the *before* version of the row, not the *after* version. If you're auto-generating queries, isn't it just as easy to have the code dump the formula twice, as it is to pick some other column to reference? Then again, what is the point of storing the same value twice? You could always generate two `UPDATE` statements too as an alternative.

Comment: The point - I really want something like this: SET col1 = 5+10, col2 = col1 * 50, where "col1 * 50" is a text formula. Otherwise, I have to replace col1 with (5+10).

Comment: Still don't understand the issue. If you have a token where you slide in the 100 (SET col1 = ?), can't you do the same thing at SET col2 = (? * 50)?

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. What difference does it make if you generate (5+10) once or twice?

Comment: I can, but this will require processing the right side of the "col2 = ?" expression, instead of simple concatenation of a precached text string (which is already exists as formula in another table).

Comment: So all of your columns are named col1 and col2? You're going to have to compromise here, because SQL Server doesn't work the way you want it to. You're either going to have to update twice, or you're going to have to use more complex string manipulation. There is no magic we're keeping from you.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a scalar function? That way you can encapuslate your code into one place and call it for each column you wish to update. You can even pass in paramaters to it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[doStuff]
(
    @myInput
)
RETURNS INT 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VAL INT

SET @VAL = @myInput * 100

RETURN @VAL    
END
```

Then you do this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET col1 = [dbo].doStuff(1), col2 = [dbo].doStuff(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always have your code generate two update statements:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Col1 = 100;
UPDATE MyTable SET Col2 = Col1;
```

But then if your queries are actually realistic and you have a `WHERE` clause, you have to repeat the `WHERE` clause twice, so you haven't really gained anything.

Comment: I'd like to avoid double triggering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the calculation in a `cross apply` and use the value in the update to avoid adding the same logic in more than one place.

```
declare @T table (Col1 float, Col2 float)

insert into @T values(1, 2),(3, 4)

update T set
  Col1 = C.Value,
  Col2 = C.Value * pi() / 4
from @T as T
  cross apply (select 100*100) as C(Value)
```